# How to install angularjs on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

How to install angularjs on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS??
I already have nodejs and npm installed. What is next step?

Answer (score 3):

To install globally use:

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

To install locally for project only:

```
npm install --save angular
```

More information:

https://gist.github.com/tusharbabbar/d8fc8d3448db6085bae6

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular